# Setting line-height globally in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How do I set the default line-height globally in Ionic 3?
In earlier versions there seems to have been an Ionic Sass variable for this, for example:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-base/blob/master/www/lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss

But no longer in Ionic 3:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/
Am I correct or am I missing something?

Edit: What I am doing now is setting the line-height in each page scss, which works fine, but I want to be able to do it globally, in one single place.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `.scss` file in assets and import it into `app.scss` on like following

`@import '../assets/scss/common.scss';`

Comment: What do you mean should be the contents of common.scss?

Comment: what ever you want to define them as globally. Just group them into common and import into `app.scss`, just user defined name.